# I am doing junior programmer : create with code 1 and keep getting error CS0103 onj line 19

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What is wrong with this code? why do i get this error? What do i do to not get this error. I have to put more text to post this question

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    public float horizantalInput;
    public float turnspeed;
    public float speed = 20;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward*Time.deltaTime*speed);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * turnspeed * horizantalInput);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what error do you get, and on which line?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: I don't see `transform` defined as a class variable.  Is that the error?

Comment: @TimRoberts this is Unity - transform should be shorthand for this.gameObject.transform.

Answer (score 1):

You define horizontal with a spelling error:

```
public float horizantalInput;
```

and then you try to use it with it spelled correctly

```
horizontalInput = //...
```

horizantal vs horizontal.

And stack overflow isn't terrible - you got your answer - but you make it hard for us to help you when you don't provide helpful details like the verbatim error, etc.